# Mavericks: How to ADD Input Source via plists/defaults?

Tags: macos, keyboard, preferences, defaults, input-source

I'm trying to automate my OS X setup but I'm stuck trying to programmatically add a new Input Source or keyboard layout.

I usually use two layouts: regular US and US International, so what I'm trying to do is just add the US International layout.

Here's what I noticed so far. When I manually add the layout, I see this entry being added to my `AppleEnabledInputSources` key on the `com.apple.HIToolbox` plist:

```
--- a/def0.txt
+++ b/def1.txt
@@ -17,6 +17,11 @@
                 {
             "Bundle ID" = "com.apple.PressAndHold";
             InputSourceKind = "Non Keyboard Input Method";
+        },
+                {
+            InputSourceKind = "Keyboard Layout";
+            "KeyboardLayout ID" = 15000;
+            "KeyboardLayout Name" = "USInternational-PC";
         }
     );
     AppleInputSourceHistory =     (
```

I got this output by doing `defaults read com.apple.HIToolbox`. I can confirm the same addition by directly opening `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`.

So I decided that probably all I had to do was just add the same entry and it would all work. So I reverted the manual addition (and confirmed the entry from the plist was gone) and now tried:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.HIToolbox AppleEnabledInputSources -array-add '{InputSourceKind="Keyboard Layout"; "KeyboardLayout Name"="USInternational-PC"; "KeyboardLayout ID"=15000;}'
```

I confirm again via `defaults read` diffs that it adds the same entry to the plist, but it doesn't work!

I tried killing `cfprefsd` and `SystemUIServer` and even rebooting but none of these seem to work.

Does anyone have a clue about what might be happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the format I used for the `AppleEnabledInputSources` entry was bad because it considers everything as type `string`, but `KeyboardLayout ID` must be of type `integer`!

So the correct way of doing this would be via XML:

```
defaults write com.apple.HIToolbox AppleEnabledInputSources -array-add '<dict><key>InputSourceKind</key><string>Keyboard Layout</string><key>KeyboardLayout ID</key><integer>15000</integer><key>KeyboardLayout Name</key><string>USInternational-PC</string></dict>'
```

After running that command and doing a logout/login, looks like things work fine.