# How to change MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 Input Sources without admin privileges and no internet connection

Tags: keyboard, catalina, input-source

I'm trying to change the input source **from ABC** to a different keyboard layout (I need to be able to choose any of them), but cannot find a way.

This iMac runs Catalina 10.15.7 has **no internet** connection and the user is **not administrator** as it is a managed iMac. I can modify stuff as administrator by I need it to persist for the rest of the users.
When I try to change the Input Source through the System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Source pane, it is not saved and does not give feedback.

I did some research and found about the existence of .keylayout files, which didn't work either. I also tried using `fs_usage` to register every file interaction System Preferences may have, no results either.

The only way I'm able to change the keyboard layout is through the `languagesetup` command (which changes the whole system language).
Other System Preferences (eg. dark theme) are saved perfectly.

If you know how MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 handles permission at System Preferences, or why it doesn't switch input sources I'd deeply appreciate it.

Comment: @TomGewecke the problem persist for every other language as well. Edited to avoid confusion

Comment: I need the capability of swapping to any other input method, whilst keeping the UI in English @TomGewecke

Comment: When you say “manged Mac”, is it just that you can’t unlock the preference panes?

Comment: No, I mean I have access to setup stuff on it as administrator, but I need to apply the change for other users. They don't have internet and they don't have admin privileges.

Comment: Aah - so you don’t have MDM set up to push changes to several Macs that need this handled without user being an admin?

Comment: @bmike I just edited the post. I do have admin privileges, but I need to change something that persists for the rest of the users and allow them to add and delete input sources. I use Ansible, but that's not something that provides useful information towards solving this problem.

Comment: This is old but may offer some kind of clue:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127246/mavericks-how-to-add-input-source-via-plists-defaults